# What the custom UUID mean for BLE in IOS Sample?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am new to iOS development, and study about **`Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE, Bluetooth 4.0)`** for IOS.

I studied the sample code of this link [BTLE Central Peripheral Transfer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Listings/BTLE_Transfer_AppDelegate_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927-BTLE_Transfer_AppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_4).

And there is another similar sample in this link [iOS 7 SDK: Core Bluetooth - Practical Lesson](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-practical-lesson--mobile-20741)

The applications on the above two links talk about `send and receive the text data` between two IOS device base on `BLE`.
The App can select to be a `central` or `Peripheral` , and the `central` will receive the text data send from the `Peripheral`.

It define the **`UUID`** like the following code in `header file`.

```
#define TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID    @"08590F7E-DB05-467E-8757-72F6FAEB13D4"
```

And after the **`Central`** connect to the **`Peripheral`** , it discover the characteristic  from **`Peripheral`**.

If the **`UUID`** is equal to **`TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID`** ,then subscribe it by using **`setNotifyValue:YES`** like the following code.

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    // Again, we loop through the array, just in case.
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {

        // And check if it's the right one
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]) {

            // If it is, subscribe to it
            [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }
    }

    // Once this is complete, we just need to wait for the data to come in.
}
```

**`The question is like the following:`**

**`First Question:`**

I can not find this **`UUID:@"08590F7E-DB05-467E-8757-72F6FAEB13D4"`** in [Bluetooth Development Portal](https://developer.bluetooth.org/Pages/default.aspx).
Is that create by **`uuidgen`** in **`terminal`** ?

**`The second Question:`**

If I am **`Central`** ,and I have subscribe the **`characteristic`** by using **`setNotifyValue:YES`** like the above code.

The BLE will tell the **`Central`** there has new data send from **`Peripheral`** by following code , is the concept correct ?

`- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error`

I am new in IOS development and BLE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the first question:
Long UUID are custom UUID (whereas standard ones use 4hex). It means they don't respect any standard, because they don't exists yet or because they are particular/propiertary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First question:

- Yes, Apple even suggests generating those UUIDs using `uuidgen` in the various WWDC video. The 128-bit UUIDs are not standardized by the Bluetooth SIG and you can use those to run your own profiles.

Second question:

- Yes, you first discover the services, then the characteristics, then `setNotifyValue:YES`. From now on, you will receive notifications from the peripheral via `[-CBPeripheralDelegate didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:]`. The same callback will be invoked when you read a characteristic manually (there's no way to distinguish the read response from a notification in Core Bluetooth).

Comment: Also, to avoid getting confused by all the different kinds of IDs: https://devforums.apple.com/message/957469#957469